# Get sortable index on click

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-sortable

I would like to get the index of the list item `<li>` that I have clicked when using jquery ui sortable. I can get it using the sortable 'start' and 'stop' events, but how would I get it just using a click of the sortable item itself.

Here is what I use to get it on a 'stop' event:

```
stop: function(event, ui){
endpos = ui.item.index() + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".sortable").click(function(){
    var theIndex = $(this).index();
});
```

Comment: sometimes the answers are just too simple aren't they... Thank you.

Comment: When I try it I get '0' no matter which element I click. I copied and pasted without changing a thing.. Am I missing anything?